# Why characters can be converted to Bytes

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character

I have a question related to character encodings in computing (ASCII and UTF-8) and would be very grateful if anyone can help me.

We know that for a computer absolutely everything is sequences of bytes, that is, the texts and characters that we humans know are just graphical representations of the sequences of bytes interpreted by the computer.

I've read in several articles that encodings are the process of mapping characters to binaries for storage in memory. But that doesn't make sense because for the computer all the data is just bytes, so for the computer, it would be the same as mapping bytes to bytes.

I would like to know if what I am saying makes sense to you?

Comment: Unicode has so many characters, they couldn't possibly all fit in a single byte.  In fact they initially thought they might be able to fit them all in 2 bytes, but they were wrong.

Comment: [1] In your question there is no explicit mention of code points, which are central to understanding how Unicode, and encoding, works. See [section 2.4 of the Unicode Standard](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/UnicodeStandard-13.0.pdf#G5.25564), _"Code Points and Characters"_ for a high level overview. [2] My suggestion is to focus first on how things work _conceptually_. Otherwise you will just get confused, and bogged down in details that hinder real understanding. You can focus on the mapping details later.

Comment: ...[3] Also, your statement that _"...all the data is just bytes, so for the computer, it would be the same as mapping bytes to bytes"_ is incorrect. Again from the Unicode Standard section 2.4: _"On a computer, abstract characters are encoded **internally as numbers**"_. Those numbers are Unicode code points,  each corresponding to some specific Unicode character. An encoding such as ASCII, UTF-8 or UTF-16 will map that Unicode code point to a sequence of one or more bytes to represent the character, where that representation may (or may not) vary between different encodings.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: first thanks for the answer, but still i can't understand the statement "In a computer, abstract characters are internally encoded as numbers"... because the "numbers" resulting from character encoding ARE ALSO BYTES (or bits) internally.
In other words, for us humans there is a difference between characters and binary numbers, but for computers there are only binaries. So, it is understood that for the
  computer encoding a character to binary is the same as encoding binaries to binaries.

Comment: A byte is limited to the range of 0 to 255 or -128 to 127.  Even simple integers need to be encoded if they're outside of that range - perhaps you've heard of the difference between [little-endian and big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?  Unicode is a little more complex than that, but the principle is the same - there's *agreed conventions* on how to convert those codepoints to bytes and back again.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, a computer has to store characters in some manner of bytes, but that storage ideally is opaque.  A "string" can store "characters", but exactly how those characters are encoded in memory is up to the program.

*Encoding* is the process of taking a "character" and converting it to a *specific* byte representation.

*Decoding* is the process of taking a specific byte representation and converting it back to the program's notion of a "character".

As a specific example, the Python language has a "text" type made of of Unicode code points, and a "bytes" type that is made up of byte values 0-255.  You don't really need to know how the text string is stored in memory, and in fact it has changed by compile options and Python version over the years (UTF-16, UTF-32, and currently a variable encoding depending on the maximum codepoint present in the string).  The text string can be encoded to a byte string and decoded back to a text string:

```py
>>> s = '你好'  # Two Chinese characters, How are the stored in memory? Does it matter?
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> len(s)
2
>>> b = s.encode('utf8')
>>> type(b)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> len(b)
6
>>> print(b)
b'\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd'  # 6 bytes encoding the 2 characters in UTF-8
>>> b.decode('utf8')         # decode from UTF-8 back to text
'你好'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ascii each character is assigned a bit pattern consisting of 7 bits. Since each bit can assume two values, there are 128 different bit patterns, which can also be interpreted as the integers 0-127 (hexadecimal 00h-7Fh).

In UTF-8 encoding, each Unicode character is assigned a specially encoded string of variable length. UTF-8 supports character strings up to a length of four bytes, to which - as with all UTF formats - all Unicode characters can be mapped.